# SocketServer.Accept() impact?

Tags: java, android, sockets

I have an Android service running in the background, it will be using this code:

```
while(true)
{
  ServerSocket server = new ServerSocket(1234);
  Socket server_socket = server.accept();
}
```

Will this loop impact battery life if it stops at `server.accept();` until a client is connected to the service?

I read the documentation but I wasn't able to find a clear answer on how `accept();` waits for requests.

If that is not the best approach for making an android device wait for socket connection request, can someone please shed the light on a better one?

Comment: It should be a blocking call, so not squander CPU cycles.  More importantly, there's not anything there which would keep the phone from going to sleep - though you may have to add that if you want the program to be useful - and if you do, that *will* cost something, especially if you must also keep the wifi active.

Comment: @ChrisStratton actually I have this in the app manifest: `<action android:name="android.net.wifi.WIFI_STATE_CHANGED" />` so the service will start once wifi is turned on, and stop once wifi is turned off by the user. Does this have negative effect?

Answer (score 2):

`accept()` is a blocking call.
You can control how long it blocks for by setting http://download.java.net/jdk7/archive/b123/docs/api/java/net/ServerSocket.html#setSoTimeout(int)

In your code you dispose of the `Socket server_socket = server.accept();` as soon as you accept it. I hope that it is not the case and you actually start a thread to handle the connection

Comment: Yes the handling will be done using an AsyncTask. However, the service will run once it receives wifi state change by Android check if its on, and stop once it receives another wifi state to check if wifi is turned off so the service stops it self. so does this impact battery life if the `accept();` is called as long as wifi is on?

Comment: I can't tell you how `accept()` is implemented on hardware level. It can be easily implemented to wait for requests using very little power, but may still scan for other devices...

Comment: Thanks, I will complete my app, do tests and collect battery life data that Android generates. 
By the way what exactly did you mean by "it can be easily implemented to wait for requests using very little power"?

Comment: accept() is passive.  But keeping the radio going is not.

Comment: @ChrisStratton **And** keeping the device switched on will use the battery too. Therefore the only power efficient way is to switch it all off and remove the battery. Obviously the radio will use the power but it's power use is neither controlled nor affected by the code.

Comment: Not by this code, but the code which could accomplish this goal would affect radio power usage.  There are many degrees of power usage.

Comment: @ChrisStratton is it going to be a part of socket listener process? You have to switch on the radio (network) in order to listen to incoming connections. If your radio (network) is off then you can not accept connections, there will be none. Or do you know how to connect to wireless network without switching on the radio?

Comment: That was exactly my point.  The code posted here won't keep the radio on while it is waiting for a connection, so it probably won't work very well.  Code which does keep the radio on *would* have a battery life impact.  And as long as it's on, any authorized program can use it, regardless if that program is the reason it is on.